# understanding cycles in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm having some difficulty understanding this issue of cycles in the permutation group ($S_n$), under the subject of abstract algebra.

The question is as follows (translated, pardon math inaccuracies):

Find $3$ elements  $s \in S_9$ such that $s^3 = (157)(283)(469)$.

The answer says, since the order of $s^3$ is $3$, the order of $s$ is $9$.

So I denoted $s^3$ as $t$, and now the order of $t$ is the lcm of the $3$ disjoint cycles, hence $3$. Now, it kinda makes sense why $s$ itself is of order $9$, but I'm not sure I would have come to this conclusion by myself. Could someone please explain?

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You've just given a perfectly good explanation for why the order of $s$ is $9$. Another way to see this is simply by observing that $1 = (s^3)^3 = s^9$.

Comment: my question is, I don't see how the order of $s^3$ gives me information about *s*'s order.

Comment: Knowing that $s^9=1$ and $s^3\ne1$ gives you enough information to deduce the $s$'s order

Answer (score 3):

The question, as I understand it, is to find three elements $s \in S_9$ that satisfy $s^3 = (157)(283)(469)$. To make this the case, each of the numbers in $(157)$, $(283)$, and $(469)$ have to be separated by two numbers. One example of a valid $s$ would be

$$s = (124586739)$$

Another would be

$$s = (142568793)$$

See if you can find the third.

Concerning why $s$ must have order 9, the order of $s$ must divide 9 (Lagrange's Theorem). Since $s^3 \ne \text{id}$, the order of $s$ cannot be 3 or 1. Thus, the order of $s$ must be 9.

Comment: Confused? s^3 is another 9-cycle in both your examples, certainly not a product of 3 cycles.

Comment: Not according to wolfram alpha, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutation+(124586739)%5E3

Comment: You're right, my bad.